# How to upload a file to an API

Tags: php, httprequest, image-uploading

Let's suppose I have a PHP server. I am creating an API for this server. I would expect to receive a request, where

```
$_POST["FileContent"]
```

would contain the file content and

```
$_POST["FileName"]
```

would contain the name of the file. My problem is that I have not done anything like that and the only way I can upload a file in this moment is using an input of type file. If I just load the file in a binary way, then I would like to use a best-practice approach and I would also like to make sure that the content is really an image content and not a PHP upload injection, for instance. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use a base64 function and then post data on server. Or you can use the $_FILES to make a classic upload ...

Comment: base64 where? Android? IOS? My web playground?

Comment: I would really like to know why is my question so bad that it is being down-voted. Am I missing something here? I am asking about a way to do this without <input type="file" name="votemedowncauseyouwerebornwiththisknowledge">

Comment: Do not care about downvoters, most of time they are just ignorants unable to give a help, they just downvote to convince themselves they worth something

Comment: I have to thank both Albanx and Kylehyde215, their initial idea led me to solve the problem both at the server side and I have also created a very nice feature in the playground to test it. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should base64 encode the file contents on the client-side, and base64 decode on the API side.

```
// client (pseudo-code)
data = {FileName: "someFileName", FileContents: base64Encode(someFile)}

// api
$fileContents = base64_decode($_POST['FileContents']);
$fileName     = $_POST['FileName'];

file_put_contents('path/to/upload/' . $fileName, $fileContents);
```

Comment: This sounds nicely, I will try it out. Unfortunately I have to go for a few minutes, but I will test your idea and if it is a valid answer, then I will upload and accept it. So you are saying I should base 64 on any client

Comment: Yes. Whatever is sending the request to the API will need to base64 encode the file contents. Now, if that client is just a javascript front-end, I'm not sure that is possible. Maybe with the new File API, but I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: it is possible both with File Api and base64 functions. Important to know is how the file is selected: if html then use file API and post file with ajax using FORMDATA, if android then I am pretty sure that there is a base64 built in function

Comment: I already know this answer deserves at least an upvote, but I am still creating the proof-of-concept